# Так как же писать скорую: с кавычками или без?

Tags: кавычки

Есть издание «Большой справочник по русскому языку» 2008 года издания. Там скорые все закавычены. Грамота дает без кавычек. Как все-таки писать?

Answer (score 2):

Постановка кавычек зависит **от текста.**

1) Сам термин ***скорая помощь*** пишется без кавычек.

2) Но в выражении приехала "скорая помощь", стояла "скорая помощь"  кавычки ставятся, так как это **условное название** (на самом деле приехала или стояла машина скорой помощи).

Примеры: В переулках и тупичках Эйн-Керема ночью может заблудиться кто угодно, не только **«скорая помощь».** [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]

На удивление быстро прибыла **и «скорая помощь».** [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но… (2011)]

Стояла во дворе **и «скорая помощь»** ― кому-то стало плохо. [Алексей Слаповский. Большая Книга Перемен // «Волга», 2010]

3) Но: *Увезли на скорой в больницу. Вызвать скорую. Врач скорой.* Здесь термин ***скорая*** используется в разных значениях, кавычки не ставятся.

― Может, всё-таки вызвать наркологию? **Или скорую?** Денис молчал. [Алексей Иванов. Комьюнити (2012)] [

4) Но доктор, который делал мне операцию, ― не тот, **который приезжал на (машине) скорой помощи,** а совсем другой доктор, Владимир Степанович, начал со мной разговаривать. [Дина Сабитова. (2011)]

Здесь **нет кавычек**, так как можно вставить пропущенное слово ***на машине*** (управление сохраняется).

5) Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Публикуется в авторской редакции **2014 года**.

**СКОРАЯ,** -ой; ж. Разг. Служба экстренной медицинской помощи при угрожающих жизни и здоровью человека состояниях; специализированная машина такой службы. ***Вызвать скорую. Пришла с. Врач скорой.***

Грамота.ру в своих ответах не учитывает, в каком предложении использовано сочетание ***скорая помощь***, а это важно.

[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=КОРАЯ](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%AF)

Comment: А чем отлисается пример 4 от примера 3? В обоих случачх подразумевается "машина".

Comment: К тому же "скорая" давно стало привычным, обыденном словом. Поэтому для каввчек нет никаких оснований.

Comment: Серж, мы используем слово "скорая" как существительное, поэтому кавычки не нужны в любых предложениях. Если мы используем сочетание "скорая помощь",  то оно должно вписываться в структуру предложения. Врач скорой помощи - кавычки  не нужны, а приехала "скорая помощь" - кавычки нужны. И дело не в привычности сочетания, а в том, что может приехать машина, но не помощь. Поэтому в книгах известных современных писателей кавычки ставятся, и это факт. Словосочетание не обладает такой грамматической свободой, как слово. Я не могу, например, написать так: из скорой помощи вышли двое врачей.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит "приехала машина, а не помощь". Говоря приехала скорая/ скорая помощь мы и так подразумеваем машину с бригадой врачей, готовых оказать помощь.

Comment: И да, скорая - это разговорный вариант, литературный вариант: скорая помощь. Мы модеи  сказать: из скорой помощи вышли двое врачей.

Comment: Сказать-то можно, но я не уверена, что редактор приличного издания это пропустит.  В этом случае надо говорить так: из машины  скорой помощи вышли двое врачей.  И вот здесь общеизвестное выражение скорая помощь заключать в кавычки не нужно. Скорая помощь - это сокращенное название, а полное название - это Служба скорой медицинской помощи. А на Ваш вариант без кавычек ссылка на правило нужна. В словаре рассматривается только слово "скорая", а не сочетание.

Comment: Скорая помощь — 1) вид и система медицинской помощи при угрожающих жизни и здоровью человека состояниях, оказываемая на месте происшествия, в пути следования, на дому; 2) автомашина, специально оборудованная, приезжающая с врачом к больному и при необходимости доставляющая больного в лечебное учреждение.

Comment: Источник (печатная версия): Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999; (электронная версия):

Comment: Серж, эта информация ничего не меняет: нельзя выходить из скорой помощи, потому что без кавычек эта фраза воспринимается дословно: выходить из помощи. Это формальная стилистическая некорректность, которая раздражает слух.

Comment: Вы исходите из субъективного мнения. И по поводу кавычек. в словаре В. Ответ Грамоты. В. Лопатина, И. В. Нечаевой, Л. К. Чельцовой. «Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой?» (М., 2002, т. е. более поздний по времени) приведена рекомендация писать _скорая помощь_ ***без кавычек***. Таким образом, очевидна тенденция к написанию скорой помощи без кавычек.

Comment: Хорошо, Серж, давайте не будем спорить. Пусть я исхожу из субъективного мнения, но оно основано на общем принципе составления текста (любого). Лично я не могу написать, что врачи выходят из скорой помощи. Пусть они лучше выходят из скорой или из машины скорой помощи. Про советы Грамоты я уже сказала в ответе, что они рассматривают словосочетание в отрыве от текста.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92888/discussion-between--and-sharon).

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки могут ставить человека читающего в тупик, или «на паузу»: *неотложная* и *скорая*, как *белое* и *красное*, *полусухое* и *шипучее* (простите за снижение уровня темы) — вполне самодостаточные слова, ставшие в своё время существительными.

Тем не менее, примеров «*скорых*», «*Скорых*», «*неотложных Скорых*», «*неотложных скорых*» в Нацкорпусе РЯ множество.